# size of ENUM columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, enums

How do databases (mySQL if a particular example is important) determine the size of the column needed to store an ENUM?

Is it something simple like a single byte for less than 256 enum options, etc.?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

MySQL Manual says "1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of enumeration values". If the ENUM has less than 256 possible values, it uses 1 byte, otherwise 2.

See: [10.5. Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

Comment: thanks! I guess i need to stop referring to this nutshell book.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` items looks like a string data type but under hood it stores like an integer.
To store a number from 0 to 255 we need 1 byte.
It's because of a byte contains 8 bites.
If all of bites in a byte be 1 it will be: 11111111
If we transfer this number to a humanity number it is 255.
so, by 1 byte we can save 0 to 255 number.

so when we define a filed like this => Enum('yes','no') it is actually like this: 1,2

It does not matter you change it to Enum('y','n'), it needs still 1 byte.
It does not matter if you add many items to this list like this:
Enum('yes','no','foo',...,'bar') until you items count is under 255.